# Display default image and replace that image with the uploaded image in android

Tags: android

I want to upload an image to particular id in server from my app and display it immediately getting a toast message as "uploaded".If there is no image exists for that particular id then I want to display some default image and later I want to replace it with the uploaded image.how can I do this?

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_details);
            {
            String IMAGE_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/mobile_app/" + img_path + "/" + img_name;
            new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ProfilePicIV))
                    .execute(IMAGE_URL);
            }


    public void onResume()
        {  // After a pause OR at startup
            super.onResume();
            getIntent();
            String auid_num = auid_s.getText().toString();
            String imei_num = imei_s.getText().toString();
            String img_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("img_name");
            String img_path = getIntent().getStringExtra("img_path");
            //Refresh your stuff here
            SendDataToServer(auid_num, imei_num);
           String IMAGE_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/mobile_app/" + img_path + "/" + img_name;
          new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ProfilePicIV))
                    .execute(IMAGE_URL);

        }

  private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

xml:
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ProfilePicIV"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@drawable/default_image"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: `want to upload an image to particular id in server`. Ok upload to a server i understand. But to a particular id? No idea! `and display it immediately`. Well to display an image you do not have to upload it first. And if you want to display it immediately, before uploading, you can assign it to an image view. So what would be problematic?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Picasso library to show your image from and use your code just to download it. Add this in your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

and use

```
Picasso.with(context).load(uri).error(R.drawable.default_image).into(imageview);
```

Comment: I have used this.But it is not displaying updated image after uploading mage to server

Comment: after i will send you by complete

Comment: I have edited code in my question.I tried with Picasso.But I did not get expected result.So I used this.Problem is if I display default image it is not getting replaced with the uploaded image for the first time even though image is uploaded in the server.

Comment: Of course. Picasso is already finished. How should Picasso know that you uploaded a new file for the image to your server? Makes no sense. Didn't you ask this before? I gave you the same info then.